# JSON column making phpmyadmin crash

Tags: mysql, json, phpmyadmin

I was using mysql 5.5. But I wanted to insert JSON columns in a table. Since JSON is supported since mysql 5.7, I upgraded to 5.7.22 (by upgrading first to 5.6 and then to 5.7 as advised online). After the upgrade, my database works fine on 5.7.22.

Now I tried to add a JSON column using phpmyadmin. But I had phpmyadmin 4.0.10, which didn't support JSON. So I installed the latest version, phpmyadmin 4.8.0.1. Now I can add JSON column to a table. When adding a JSON column, the query is executed, and I can see the structure:

[image: Structure accessible]

But when I click on Browse, I have this error message:

[image: Browse not accessible]

Any idea where this comes from? How can I normally access the Browse tab when there is a JSON column in the table?

EDIT: Here are the logs of apache2 and mysql:

**error.log of apache2:**

```
[Wed May 30 17:49:00.681304 2018] [core:notice] [pid 14677] AH00051: child pid 16591 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed May 30 17:49:00.681348 2018] [core:notice] [pid 14677] AH00051: child pid 17013 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed May 30 17:49:05.687043 2018] [core:notice] [pid 14677] AH00051: child pid 17015 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

**error.log of mysql:**

```
2018-05-30T15:49:00.082385Z 303017 [Note] Aborted connection 303017 to db: 'pointageversus' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2018-05-30T15:49:00.082385Z 303018 [Note] Aborted connection 303018 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2018-05-30T15:49:00.444586Z 303019 [Note] Aborted connection 303019 to db: 'pointageversus' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2018-05-30T15:49:00.444586Z 303020 [Note] Aborted connection 303020 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2018-05-30T15:49:05.661929Z 303010 [Note] Aborted connection 303010 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2018-05-30T15:49:05.661958Z 303009 [Note] Aborted connection 303009 to db: 'pointageversus' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

**access.log of apache2:**

```
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:37 +0200] "POST /tbl_structure.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1202 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:37 +0200] "POST /tbl_create.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2684 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:37 +0200] "GET /db_structure.php?server=1&db=pointageversus&table=&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&_nocache=1527695086610245467&token=%3F0%5BgrDzF%2F_%2Bs%22%5B(D HTTP/1.1" 200 19908 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:37 +0200] "POST /navigation.php?ajax_request=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 6226 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:37 +0200] "GET /tbl_structure.php?server=1&db=pointageversus&token=?0[grDzF/_+s%22[(D&goto=db_structure.php&table=contact2&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&_nocache=1527695086624542685&token=%3F0%5BgrDzF%2F_%2Bs%22%5B(D HTTP/1.1" 200 7873 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:38 +0200] "GET /themes/pmahomme/img/b_tblimport.png HTTP/1.1" 200 839 "http://phpmyadmin.versus-alternative.ch/phpmyadmin.css.php?nocache=6102843922ltr&server=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:38 +0200] "GET /themes/pmahomme/img/b_tblexport.png HTTP/1.1" 200 797 "http://phpmyadmin.versus-alternative.ch/phpmyadmin.css.php?nocache=6102843922ltr&server=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:38 +0200] "GET /themes/pmahomme/img/s_tbl.png HTTP/1.1" 200 928 "http://phpmyadmin.versus-alternative.ch/phpmyadmin.css.php?nocache=6102843922ltr&server=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:38 +0200] "GET /themes/pmahomme/img/b_move.png HTTP/1.1" 200 664 "http://phpmyadmin.versus-alternative.ch/phpmyadmin.css.php?nocache=6102843922ltr&server=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:38 +0200] "GET /themes/pmahomme/img/normalize.png HTTP/1.1" 200 788 "http://phpmyadmin.versus-alternative.ch/phpmyadmin.css.php?nocache=6102843922ltr&server=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:38 +0200] "GET /themes/pmahomme/img/b_edit.png HTTP/1.1" 200 660 "http://phpmyadmin.versus-alternative.ch/phpmyadmin.css.php?nocache=6102843922ltr&server=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:38 +0200] "GET /themes/pmahomme/img/b_primary.png HTTP/1.1" 200 820 "http://phpmyadmin.versus-alternative.ch/phpmyadmin.css.php?nocache=6102843922ltr&server=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:38 +0200] "GET /themes/pmahomme/img/b_unique.png HTTP/1.1" 200 866 "http://phpmyadmin.versus-alternative.ch/phpmyadmin.css.php?nocache=6102843922ltr&server=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:38 +0200] "GET /themes/pmahomme/img/b_index.png HTTP/1.1" 200 927 "http://phpmyadmin.versus-alternative.ch/phpmyadmin.css.php?nocache=6102843922ltr&server=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:38 +0200] "GET /themes/pmahomme/img/b_ftext.png HTTP/1.1" 200 833 "http://phpmyadmin.versus-alternative.ch/phpmyadmin.css.php?nocache=6102843922ltr&server=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:38 +0200] "GET /js/tbl_structure.js?v=4.8.0.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 5116 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:38 +0200] "GET /navigation.php?ajax_request=1&aPath=cm9vdA%3D%3D.cG9pbnRhZ2V2ZXJzdXM%3D.dmlld3M%3D&vPath=cm9vdA%3D%3D.cG9pbnRhZ2V2ZXJzdXM%3D.Vmlld3M%3D&pos=0&pos2_name=views&pos2_value=0&searchClause=&searchClause2=&_nocache=1527695087786998417&token=%3F0%5BgrDzF%2F_%2Bs%22%5B(D HTTP/1.1" 200 2776 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:53 +0200] "GET /db_structure.php?server=1&db=pointageversus&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&_nocache=1527695102868657800&token=%3F0%5BgrDzF%2F_%2Bs%22%5B(D HTTP/1.1" 200 19928 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/May/2018:17:48:57 +0200] "GET /tbl_structure.php?db=pointageversus&table=contact2&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&_nocache=1527695106985813658&token=%3F0%5BgrDzF%2F_%2Bs%22%5B(D HTTP/1.1" 200 7853 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
```

**Result of command `php -r 'phpinfo();'`:**

https://ufile.io/68ad0

Comment: Looking at web server and mysqld logs may give some hints. Did you upgrade php mysql module too?

Comment: @YuriLachin Thanks for your reply. I edited my post and added logs. How can I check which php mysql module version I have installed ?

Comment: Either run command `php -r 'phpinfo();'` in shell or create foobar.php file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it under web server root directory and look at its url in browser. I see `Segmentaion fault` in error.log: probably  apache httpd process dies trying to access database or decode json data.

Comment: @YuriLachin I ran the command, and placed the output at the end of my post. I searched for mysql or php info in it, I couldn't find any info regarding php mysql module.

Comment: have you tried updating phpmyadmin? I guess this is a bug which was resolved in newer version. If you have control over phpmyadmin install, update it. If not, try connecting to it via MySQL Workbench (freeware from MySQL) maybe, might help.